# Mashup Wirecloud and Angular js

Tags: angularjs, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I have developed an application - widget-  via angular.js which will be hosted in WireCloud. I need to get the username of the user who is login in the Application. 
To this end, I have to use MashupPlatform.context.get('username') - but Angular doesn't understand "MashupPlatform" obviously because it is an external object.

Do you have any idea how to overtake this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it was simple. I had html links  for my routing and this was the false. I changed the routing style to javascript ( ng-click ) and It is ok.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Meier said, when your widget is loaded in Wirecloud MashupPlatform is injected, but to test it locally you can use the [`mock-mashupplatform` library](https://github.com/Wirecloud/mock-applicationmashup), it's in npm and bower.  Right now almost all wirecloud 0.7 are supported, but support to 0.8 will come this week.

For this example, you will do something like this:

```
// Create the default values in a dictionary
var preferencesValues = {
    'username': 'myusername'
};
// Construct the default values with strategies
var values = {
    'prefs.get': MockMP.strategy.dict(preferencesValues)
};

// Construct the MashupPlatform with that values
window.MashupPlatform = new MockMP.MockMP(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

MashupPlatform will be loaded (or injected) when your widget is deployed in the Wirecloud platform. If you just want to test it locally, you can ask if it is there like this:

```
if (typeof MashupPlatform === 'undefined') {
  username = "testusername";
}
else {
  username = MashupPlatform.context.get('username');
}
```

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your answer. I am not asking about the localhost (or development environment) but for the wirecloud. How could I get the username from the mashup in the angular js application..

Comment: Angular is also only javascript, so I think you should be able to access MashupPlatform. If not, where exactly do you call it, and what is happen in the javascript console?

Comment: I created a simple widget in Angular which contains angular route, a service which gets and returns tha username via MashupPlatform and a controller which asks the username from the service. 

It works perfectly in the first view but when I navigate to the second page It gives me an error **ReferenceError: MashupPlatform is not defined**.